# Installing Ubuntu 13.10 on HP Mini... freezing at (initramfs)

Tags: installation, 13.10

So I'm installing 13.10 through Virtual Box and it begins to initiate then just stops...

last message on screen is...

```
busybox v1.20.2 (Ubuntu 1:1.20.0-8.1ubuntu1) built in shell (ash) Enter 'help' for a list of built in commands. 
(initramfs)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug in 13.10 see [launchpad issue](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/casper/+bug/1241589). People have posted some solutions there like: removing hard disks physically or recreating SYSLINUX.CFG

Comment: This should be posted as a comment.

Comment: I don't have a reputation to post comments.